# Eclipse Plugin: Implement Quick Fix proposals on hovering over errors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**What i have**: I display errors in the editor as a red underline and als in the problems view. I use markers for that, but also create annotations by this code:

```
@TextEditorScoped
public class ErrorHighlighter {

  private final IAnnotationModel annotationModel;

  private String content = "";


  private final Set<Annotation> annotations = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

  private static final String ERRORMARKERID  = "org.eclipse.rwth.syntaxerror";
  private static final String WARNINGMARKERID = "org.eclipse.rwth.syntaxwarning"; 

  @Inject
  public ErrorHighlighter(@Nullable IAnnotationModel annotationModel, IStorage storage,
      ObservableModelStates observableModelStates) {
    this.annotationModel = annotationModel;
    if (annotationModel != null) {
      observableModelStates.getModelStates().stream()
          .filter(modelState -> modelState.getStorage().equals(storage))
          .forEach(this::acceptModelState);
      observableModelStates.addStorageObserver(storage, this::acceptModelState);
    }
  }

  public void acceptModelState(ModelState modelState) {
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
      annotationModel.removeAnnotation(annotation);
      annotations.remove(annotation);
    }
    IMarker[] problems = null;
    int depth = IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE;
    IFile file = Misc.getEditorInput(modelState.getStorage()).getAdapter(IFile.class);
    try { //Remove all problem Markers when rebuilding the Model
       problems = file.findMarkers(ERRORMARKERID, true, depth);
       for(IMarker m: problems){
           m.delete();
       }
       problems = file.findMarkers(WARNINGMARKERID, true, depth);
       for(IMarker m: problems){
           m.delete();
       }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        content = IOUtils.toString(modelState.getStorage().getContents(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    displaySyntaxErrors(modelState);
    displayAdditionalErrors(modelState);
  }

  private void displaySyntaxErrors(ModelState modelState) {
    ImmutableMultimap<Interval, String> syntaxErrors = modelState.getSyntaxErrors();
    for (Interval interval: syntaxErrors.keys()) {
      for (String message : syntaxErrors.get(interval)) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> displayError(interval, message));
      }
    }
  }

  private void displayAdditionalErrors(ModelState modelState) {
    Multimap<Interval, String> additionalErrors = modelState.getAdditionalErrors();
    for (Interval interval: additionalErrors.keys()) {
      for (String message : additionalErrors.get(interval)) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> displayError(interval, message));
      }
    }
  }

  private void displayError(Interval interval, String message) {
    int startIndex = interval.a;
    int stopIndex = interval.b + 1;
    Annotation annotation = null;
//    Annotation annotation =
//        new Annotation("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error", false, message);
//    annotations.add(annotation);
//    annotationModel.addAnnotation(annotation, new Position(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex));
    IMarker marker = null;
    try { //create Marker to display Syntax Errors in Problems View
        IFile file = (IFile) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
        if (file != null) {
            if(message.charAt(message.length()-1) == 'W'){
                marker = file.createMarker(WARNINGMARKERID);
                marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
            } else {
                marker = file.createMarker(ERRORMARKERID);
                marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            }
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, startIndex);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, stopIndex);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            int lineNumber = 0;
            if(!content.isEmpty() && content.length()>=stopIndex){  //Convert StartIndex to Line Number
                String[] lines = content.substring(0, stopIndex).split("\r\n|\r|\n");
                lineNumber = lines.length;
            }
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IMarker[] problems = null;
    int depth = IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE;
    IFile file = (IFile) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
    try { //Remove all problem Markers when rebuilding the Model
       problems = file.findMarkers(ERRORMARKERID, true, depth);
       for(IMarker m: problems){
           for(IMarker n: problems){
               if(MarkerUtilities.getCharStart(m) == MarkerUtilities.getCharStart(n) && m != n && MarkerUtilities.getMessage(m).equals(MarkerUtilities.getMessage(n))){
                   m.delete();
               }
           }
       }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(marker != null){
        Annotation a = new MarkerAnnotation(marker);
        annotations.add(a);
        annotationModel.addAnnotation(a, new Position(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex));
    }

  }
}
```

In my SourceViewerConfiguration I overwrite getTextHover and getAnnotationHover with this code:

```
@Override
  public IAnnotationHover getAnnotationHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
      return new DefaultAnnotationHover(true);
  }

  public ITextHover getTextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {
      return new DefaultTextHover(sourceViewer);
  }
```

I also overwrite getQuickAssistAssistant with this code:

```
public IQuickAssistAssistant getQuickAssistAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
      IQuickAssistAssistant quickAssist = new QuickAssistAssistant();
      quickAssist.setQuickAssistProcessor(new TFQuickAssistProcessor());
      quickAssist.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));
      return quickAssist;
}
```

With this i can right klick on errors in the code and select QuickFix, which will result in a Box appearing, which displays my Quick Fix Proposals.

**What I want**: How do I make this Box appear whenever I hover above the error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: 
I replaced the `getTextHover` method by this one:

```
public ITextHover getTextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {      
      return new AbstractAnnotationHover(true) {
          public Object getHoverInfo2(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
              IAnnotationModel model = ((SourceViewer) textViewer).getAnnotationModel();
              @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              Iterator<Annotation> parent = 
                      ((IAnnotationModelExtension2)model).getAnnotationIterator(hoverRegion.getOffset(), 
                              hoverRegion.getLength(), true, true);
              Iterator<?> iter = new JavaAnnotationIterator(parent, false); 
              Annotation annotation = null;
              Position position = null;
              while (iter.hasNext()) {
                  Annotation a = (Annotation) iter.next();
                  Position p = model.getPosition(a);
                  annotation = a;
                  position = p;
              }
              return new AnnotationInfo(annotation, position, textViewer) {
                  public ICompletionProposal[] getCompletionProposals() {
                      ICompletionProposal proposal1 = null;
                      IMarkerResolution [] resolutions = null;
                      ICompletionProposal [] com = null;
                      if (annotation instanceof MarkerAnnotation) {
                          resolutions = new ErrorResolution().getResolutions(((MarkerAnnotation) annotation).getMarker());
                          if(resolutions.length != 0){
                              proposal1 = new MarkerResolutionProposal(resolutions[0], 
                                      ((MarkerAnnotation) annotation).getMarker());
                              return new ICompletionProposal[] { proposal1 };
                          }
                      }
                      return com ;
                  }
              };
          } 
    };
}
```

which will result in a hovering box appearing over the errors offering a quick fix. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm doing something similar, but the hiver control that appears is not scrollable, even when I have more text than fits in the window. Do you have the same behavior? Thee must be a way to make it work because the JDT QuickFix hover is scrollable when needed.

Comment: The scrollbar was not being drawn because I had a bug in which my proposal list was empty. The hover control skips setting up the scrollbars if the AnnotationInfo set as input has no completion proposals.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Even with a proposal included, the hover doesn't draw any scrollbars as it does for JDT QuickFix proposals. I'm looking at the code in AbstractInformationControlManager in the debugger, and I can't see why the scrollable is not being set up correctly when I show the information control.

Comment: I was trying to use the JDT hover to also provide regular textual help info, and that's not the right way to do it. I posted a separate answer with code for a delegating hover implementation, for any others who want to provide more than one type of hover info.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer solved my problem, but I also needed to provide textual hover help in addition to the problem resolution proposals. Different hover implementations are needed for textual help and problem resolution proposals.

Here's my implementation of a delegating Hover control, which calls the JDT Annotation hover control if the user is hovering over a problem marker and a resolution proposal is available. Otherwise, it calls an ITextHover implementation which provides textual help if available.

This is loosely based on the JDT implementation of `BestMatchHover`, which is how the JDT delegates to different Hovers by checking configured hovers in turn and using the first one which returns information. I had some trouble getting the proper presentation from the selected hover, and the JDT implementation was helpful in showing how to provide the appropriate implementations of `IInformationControlCreator`.

```
/**
 * This class provides a TextHover implementation which delegates to one of two different kinds of
 * TextHovers, depending on the current hover contents.
 * 
 * If the mouse is hovering over text for which
 * a problem was detected by the parser and a resolution proposal is available, presentation of the
 * hover info will be delegated to the JDT Hover control which presents the problem description and
 * Hyperlinks for the available proposals. Otherwise an ITextHover implementation will provide textual
 * hover help..
 * 
 * The JDT Hover implementation is non-API, and could therefore break in future RCP versions.
 */

public class DelegatingTextHover implements ITextHover, ITextHoverExtension, ITextHoverExtension2 {

    private ICompletionProposal[] proposals = new ICompletionProposal[0];

    protected IRegion currentHoverRegion;

    //Provides help info as text
    private ITextHover helpHover = new ITextHover() {

        @Override
        public IRegion getHoverRegion(ITextViewer textViewer, int offset) {
            return DelegatingTextHover.this.getHoverRegion(textViewer, offset);
        }


        @Override
        public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
            String hoverHelp = ...
            return hoverHelp;

    };


    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private AbstractAnnotationHover quickFixHover = new AbstractAnnotationHover(true) {

        @Override
        public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public IRegion getHoverRegion(ITextViewer textViewer, int offset) {
            return DelegatingTextHover.this.getHoverRegion(textViewer, offset);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getHoverInfo2(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
            currentHoverRegion = hoverRegion;
            IMarker marker = ((MarkerResolutionProposal) proposals[0]).getMarker();
            String msg;
            try {
                msg = (String) marker.getAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE);
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                msg = "Parsing Error";
            }
            return new AnnotationInfo(new Annotation(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, msg),
                    new Position(hoverRegion.getOffset(), msg.length()),
                    textViewer) {
                @Override
                public ICompletionProposal[] getCompletionProposals() {
                    return proposals;
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
            // if we're using the annotation hover, delegate to superclass. Otherwise, use the default
            if (hoveringOverProblemAnnotation(currentHoverRegion)) {
                return super.getHoverControlCreator();
            }
            return new IInformationControlCreator() {
                @Override
                public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell shell) {
                    return new DefaultInformationControl(shell, true);
                }
            };
        }

    };

    @SuppressWarnings({ "restriction", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public Object getHoverInfo2(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
        proposals = ...
        if (hoveringOverProblemAnnotation(hoverRegion)) {
            return quickFixHover.getHoverInfo2(textViewer, hoverRegion);
        }
        currentHoverRegion = hoverRegion;
        return helpHover.getHoverInfo(textViewer, hoverRegion);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        if (hoveringOverProblemAnnotation(currentHoverRegion)) {
            return quickFixHover.getHoverControlCreator();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IRegion getHoverRegion(ITextViewer textViewer, int offset) {
        Point selection= textViewer.getSelectedRange();
        if (selection.x <= offset && offset < selection.x + selection.y)
            return new Region(selection.x, selection.y);
        return new Region(offset, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean hoveringOverProblemAnnotation(IRegion hoverRegion) {
        List<Point> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ICompletionProposal proposal : proposals) {
            //MarkerResolutionProposal is an implementation of ICompletionProposal which wraps a Marker
            if (proposal instanceof MarkerResolutionProposal) {
                MarkerResolutionProposal markerProposal = (MarkerResolutionProposal) proposal;
                IMarker marker = markerProposal.getMarker();
                try {
                    Integer begin =  (Integer) marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START);
                    Integer end = (Integer) marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END);
                    ranges.add(new Point(begin, end));
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    //PASS
                }
            }
        }
        boolean found = false;
        for (Point p : ranges) {
            if (hoverRegion.getOffset() >= p.x && hoverRegion.getOffset() <= p.y) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        return proposals.length > 0 && found;
    }

}
```